# Identifying Facebook Messenger Lite users

Tags: facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Facebook Messenger Lite users cannot see galleries nor many of the other richer aspects of FB Messenger.

How should I identify users messaging via Facebook Messenger Lite (vs. FBM Full) so I can service them effectively without degrading the richness provided to FB Messenger Full) users?

PS someone needs to create tag "facebook-messenger-lite" - I don't have the reputation for it yet.

Comment: i am pretty sure there is no way to identify if a user uses messenger or messenger lite. after all, on desktop it would work. but i did create the tag, because it appears that there are more than a million users for messenger lite and it´s a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifying the user isn't supported in the webhook events currently. The only way is to look at the user-agent header in the webview.

Comment: That's creates a tough situation for providing a good user experience in markets where both Messenger lite and either web client or Messenger full are also in use.

Comment: Yeah right now the only way to sorta handle it is have a separate page for lite users. Back both pages with the same app then filter the responses based on which page id is in the recipient.id field of the webhook event

Comment: We've started guessing and then ask users to confirm or switch experiences. Not great but better than two pages b/c we have customers with massive page presence who won't want to launch a new page and try to build it up.